# magento 2 theme configuration not save

Tags: magento, magento2

404 error after saving to Design configuration (2.2.1) does not save. admin/system_config/save/section/porto_settings/key/42ebe2fad4e637ad0ed41c23fb772ba3e6fd8d7ab6d77d0abbf23a1569a1d721/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

edited modsecurity.conf file in server.

From: SecRuleEngine On

To: SecRuleEngine Off

Hope it helps you!